# OleDB Select command not working with multiple OR statements (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sqlcommand

I am using the below select statement to pick up data from excel and drop it into a datatable. There is a bad row in there that I do not want to pick up so thats this part [Plan] <> 'PLAN_BO' however it does not work with the other two OR statements. [Plan] should be a datetime column but there is a extra row with text.

The combination of [Plan] <> 'PLAN_BO' or [Plan] is null work together but not the three together.

```
 comm.CommandText = "Select Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW, Bldg, School, [Project Description], [Doc Avail], [Plan] from [ca_rpt$] where [Plan] <> 'PLAN_BO' or [Plan] is null or [Plan] >= DATE() order by Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW";
```

Is there a way to offset the first row because thats the bad row however its not the column titles. I tried Offset 1 Row at the end of the statement but it did not work.

Edit: Current condition

(ISDATE([Bid Open Plan]) and [Bid Open Plan] >= DATE()) or [Bid Open Plan] is null

[Bid Open Plan] >= DATE() is being ignored.

```
 using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
                using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    comm.CommandText = "Select Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW, Bldg, School, [Project Description], [Pkg#], [Doc Available], [Bid Open Plan] from(Select Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW, Bldg, School, [Project Description], [Pkg#], [Doc Available], [Bid Open Plan] from [ca_rpt$] where ISDATE([Bid Open Plan]) or [Bid Open Plan] is null) Where [Bid Open Plan] >= DATE() order by Mincat, Minse, [Pkg#], [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW";
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = comm;
                        da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to check if the column value is a valid date.you can use `ISDATE` to check if the value is a valid date and return only those which are valid.

```
  Select Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW, Bldg, School, 
    [Project Description], [Doc Avail], [Bid Open Plan] 

    FROM(
          Select Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW, Bldg, School, [Project Description], [Doc Avail], [Bid Open Plan]
          from [ca_rpt$]
          where ISDATE([Bid Open Plan]) =1 or [Bid Open Plan] is null 
    )
    WHERE [Bid Open Plan]>=Date()
    order by Category, [Project ID], Package, [Design ID], LLW
```

check this link [Documentation on ISDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Ok I used ISDATE([Plan]) and that worked thanks, but I also have the [Plan] >= DATE() condition and its getting ignored.                                                                                                                                                
(ISDATE([Bid Open Plan]) and [Bid Open Plan] >= DATE()) or [Bid Open Plan] is null

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with [plan]>=Date()?

Comment: I only need records with dates that haven passed yet. So from today and on plus any with nulls.

Comment: you would need to probably cast the string value to datetime and then compare it with todays date.so it would be   cast ([Bid Open Plan] as datetime)>=getdate()

Comment: [Bid Open Plan] is already a datetime. [Bid Open Plan] >= Date() has worked before but when adding in ISDATE([Bid Open Plan]) it gets ignored.

Comment: write a outer query to get what you need.Updated my answer

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong but that doesnt work. Data comes from excel and I posted my oleDB connection. I dont know if I am limited because its excel but I believe I wrote the query correctly.